# Optimize multiple JOINs in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join

On a website every page must contain relevant teasers leading to other pages making up a semantically relevant internal linking.

There are following tables involved:

```
pages (id, parent, ...)
teasers (id, reference, prio, start_date, expiry_date, ...)
teaser_instances(id, teaser_id, pins, type, ...)
keywords (id, content, ...)
page_keyword_rel (page_id, keyword_id)
```

A teaser has several instances to include at different parts on the target page, but the same teaser cannot be presented more than once on the same page.
A teaser is considered relevant when it is either "pinned" to the target page or belongs to the same parent page or the teaser's page contains the same keywords as the target page.

So to retrieve teasers the system generates queries like this:

```
SELECT ... 
 FROM teasers t 
 LEFT JOIN teaser_instances i on t.id = i.teaser_id 
 LEFT JOIN pages p on t.reference = p.id 
 LEFT JOIN (page_keyword_rel r 
  LEFT JOIN keywords k on r.keyword_id=k.id) on p.id=r.page_id

 WHERE 
 # relevancy criteria
 (i.pins like '%XYZ%' or p.parent= '1' or k.content IN ('A', 'B', 'C')) and 

 # exclude instances of the same teaser on a page
 t.reference != '1' and t.reference !='2' and t.reference !='3' and 

 # instance is characterized by type
 i.type='1' and 

 # exclude self targeted teasers (teaser points to the target page)
 p.id != '2' and 

 # time validity
 (not t.start_date or t.start_date<=now()) and 
 (not t.expiry_date or t.expiry_date >=now()) 

 GROUP BY t.reference
 ORDER BY (i.pins not like '%XYZ%'), prio, rand() limit 0,5;
```

The query execution time is inacceptable.

EXPLAIN gives me this:
[image]

The problem definitely dwells in the last JOIN, where it fails to use indexes (see penultimate row).
This is the relevancy check for keywords matching.

How can we optimize this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have left readers guess about what your indexes are. And you haven't mentioned what your 'inacceptable' query excution time is

Comment: The `page_keyword_rel` table has indices on both `page_id` and `keyword_id`. All `id` columns are primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your last join `on` clause is placed wrongly. it has to be

```
LEFT JOIN page_keyword_rel r on p.id=r.page_id
```

Again, move those conditions fro `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` condition since you are performing an outer join. Example `k.content IN ('A', 'B', 'C')` move this to `JOIN ON` clause

```
 LEFT JOIN keywords k on r.keyword_id=k.id
 AND k.content IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Also, make sure that the columns used in `JOIN ON` condition or `WHERE` condition, `group by` and `order by` are having proper index created on them.

Comment: I disagree. The ON clause is not missing, it's just that he is doing a NESTED JOIN.

Comment: I think you'll find the join predicate is simply outside the brackets on the next line down.

Comment: @ThomasG, what's a nested join? any idea? yes I see, on clause not missing but placed in wrong position. kind a join OP posted is not nested but rather mistaken or lack of knowledge join.

Comment: `JOIN (table JOIN table ON...) ON ... `  this is a NESTED JOIN.

Comment: @ThomasG, is it? can you point to the right documentation which says that?

Comment: Sure, look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-join-optimization.html) for instance

Comment: @ThomasG, Ok but that would become then a cross join rather

Comment: no. I think you looked at the first example only (where you have a somewhat NESTED CROSS join). Scroll a bit down and you'll find this : `t1 LEFT JOIN (t2 LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.b=t3.b OR t2.b IS NULL)
   ON t1.a=t2.a`. Nested join like the OP posted

Comment: And this is not purely MySQL: here you have explanation on what a NESTED join is and how usefull it is : http://michaeljswart.com/2012/09/when-i-use-nested-joins/